# Sharepoint CAML Fliter

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint page which shows new employees from an employee list. I uses the start date of the employee and displays them for 30 days. We have outsourced 2 departments and managers do not want to see them as new employees since they are from a third party firm. Below is the code I tried but can not get to work. I have moved the 'And' up to include all three filter and I get an error '(soap:ServerException of t.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown. Cannot complete this action. Please try again.0x80004005)'.
I move the 'And' near the 'Neq' and they get ignored. I am trying to keep the 30 days for start date and exclude the two departments.

```
`<Query>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="Full_x0020_Name"/>
    </OrderBy>
    <Where>
    <And>
  <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="StartDate"/>
      <Value Type="DateTime">
      <Today OffsetDays="-30"/>
      </Value>
      </Geq>
  <Neq>
         <FieldRef Name="Department"/>
     <Value Type="Text">G4S Security</Value>
  </Neq>
  <Neq>
     <FieldRef Name="Department"/>
     <Value Type="Text">Budd Group</Value>
  </Neq>
  </And>
      </Where>
</Query>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, there can be only two within an And. This is the code I changed below.

```
'<Where>
<And>
  <And>
   <Geq>
       <FieldRef Name="StartDate"/>
       <Value Type="DateTime">
       <Today OffsetDays="-30"/>
       </Value>
   </Geq>
   <Neq>
       <FieldRef Name="Department"/>
           <Value Type="Text">G4S Security</Value>
   </Neq>
  </And>
    <Neq>
      <FieldRef Name="Department"/>
      <Value Type="Text">Budd Group</Value>
    </Neq>
     </And>
  </Where>'
```

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms196939(v=office.14).aspx

> This element can be nested inside other And and Or elements. The server supports unlimited complicated queries. **However, any given And element can have only two conjuncts**; that is, only two child elements. If you need to conjoin three or more conditions, you must nest the And elements [...]

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name="StartDate"/>
                <Value Type="DateTime">
                    <Today OffsetDays="-30"/>
                </Value>
            </Geq>
            <Neq>
                <FieldRef Name="Department"/>
                <Value Type="Text">G4S Security</Value>
            </Neq>
        </And>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name="Department"/>
            <Value Type="Text">Budd Group</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

There is also the issue of the query method itself.
If you are using the method "query" in the "list" class, then you cannot use the `<Query></Query>` tags in your CAML. The reason is the method already wraps your query with this tag automatically and adding it breaks the query.
See my code for example:

```
    Private Function GenerateCamlForCurrentUserMessages(list As SPList, isActiveOnly As Boolean) As SPQuery
        Dim qResult As SPQuery
        Dim sCaml As String = ""
        Dim web As SPWeb = SPContext.Current.Web

        If isActiveOnly Then
            sCaml = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='User'>" & web.CurrentUser.Name.ToString() & "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='IsActive' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq></And></Where>"
        Else
            sCaml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='User'>" & web.CurrentUser.Name.ToString() & "</Value></Eq></Where>"
        End If
        qResult = New SPQuery()
        'sCaml = sCaml & list.DefaultView.Query
        qResult.Query = sCaml
        Return qResult

    End Function
```